# How to update other OrderNo when I update OrderNo of one record on tsql

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-update, cursor

I have an question table which named "Questions" and it has OrderNo which defines Order of the questions.

I faced a problem during update OrderNo.

If I update one of the OrderNo, it must be updated all OrderNo depends on an updated OrderNo therefore all orders will be updated.

One of the solution is cursor but I dont solve this issue.

Do you have any recommendation?

Comment: Hi, if you want the very best answer, or any answer really, check out [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question) and [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question)

Comment: @BarryPiccinni thank you for your answer but this is a kind of FAQ of sql

Comment: What behavior are you looking for? For example, if you change 10 to 3, are you looking for numbers >=3 and <10 to be shifted up by +1?

Comment: @user7733611 Your comment almost satisfy my request. Do you have any idea about solution

Comment: Yes it was. It will help you ask a better question, which in turn will help you bet a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

The following code demonstrates one way of repositioning a row in a given *display order* and shuffling any other rows to accommodate the change. By using a `case` expression a single `update` statement can pick and choose how to update different rows.

NB: It should be wrapped in a suitable transaction for use in The Real Word.

```
-- Sample data.
declare @Samples as Table ( Id Int Identity, DisplayOrder Int );
insert into @Samples ( DisplayOrder ) values ( 1 ), ( 2 ), ( 3 ), ( 4 );
select * from @Samples order by DisplayOrder;

-- We need a few variables.
declare @PreviousDisplayOrder as Int;
declare @Id as Int, -- Row to be moved.
  @DisplayOrder as Int; -- New order for the row.

-- Pick a row to move and a new display order for it.
select @Id = 2, @DisplayOrder = 3;

-- Determine the previous display order for the row being moved.
select @PreviousDisplayOrder = DisplayOrder from @Samples where Id = @Id;

-- Display some useful tidbits.
select @PreviousDisplayOrder as PreviousDisplayOrder,
  ( select Min( DisplayOrder ) from ( values ( @DisplayOrder ), (@PreviousDisplayOrder ) ) M1( DisplayOrder ) ) as MinDisplayOrder,
  ( select Max( DisplayOrder ) from ( values ( @DisplayOrder ), (@PreviousDisplayOrder ) ) M2( DisplayOrder ) ) as MaxDisplayOrder;

-- Update the rows.
update @Samples
  set DisplayOrder = case
    -- Set the order of the repositioned row.
    when Id = @Id then @DisplayOrder
    -- Moving the repositioned row up (numerically).
    when @DisplayOrder > @PreviousDisplayOrder and DisplayOrder <= @DisplayOrder then DisplayOrder - 1
    -- Moving the repositioned row down (numerically).
    when @DisplayOrder < @PreviousDisplayOrder and DisplayOrder >= @DisplayOrder then DisplayOrder + 1
    else DisplayOrder
    end
    where
      -- Only update the rows between the original and the new display orders.
      DisplayOrder >= ( select Min( DisplayOrder ) from ( values ( @DisplayOrder ), (@PreviousDisplayOrder ) ) M1( DisplayOrder ) ) and
      DisplayOrder <= ( select Max( DisplayOrder ) from ( values ( @DisplayOrder ), (@PreviousDisplayOrder ) ) M2( DisplayOrder ) );

-- Display the results.
select * from @Samples order by DisplayOrder;
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution but null values ignored in this script. Also if there are equal DisplayOrder values, it does not work. Your script works only identical DisplayOrder values. I will try to develop on these regardings

Comment: @MertMetin It was unclear from your question that `Questions` contains rows that have the same `OrderNo`, null `OrderNo`, ... . I wildly assumed that the values would be integers starting at `1` and proceed in a dense fashion up to the number of rows. In fact, the point of the question appeared to be updating `OrderNo` so that multiple questions wouldn't have the same value. Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.